# Integrate Sonata Media Bundle (Media Entity) and Sonata Classiffication Bundle (Tags Entity)

Tags: tags, sonata, symfony-2.4, sonata-media-bundle

I need to **integrate this two bundles** to be able to **add Tags** to an Media Entity (Image, Video, etc.).

**I'm using:**

*"sonata-project/media-bundle":"version": "2.3.1"*
*"sonata-project/classification-bundle":"version": "2.2.1"*
*"symfony/symfony":"version": "v2.4.10"*

Comment: do you plan on managing these through the admin bundle as well?

Comment: yes i do... so, when i upload an image, i could atach extra information to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sonata sandbox they demonstrate overriding entities.

I'd suggest reviewing their appbundle directory structure and configs. You may have to use the current 2.3 branch folder layout but the concept is the same.

the examples below will assume you are overriding/extending every entity. If you are only planning on overriding the media entity then I believe you would just need to change the namespace for the `AppBundle\Entity\Classification\Tag` to `Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Model\Tag` (not tested)

you could add extra properties to the media entity located [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.4-develop/src/AppBundle/Entity/Media/Media.php)

**AppBundle\Entity\Media\Media.php**

```
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection|\AppBundle\Entity\Classification\Tag[]
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->tags           = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection|\AppBundle\Entity\Classification\Tag[]
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}

/**
 * @param ArrayCollection|\AppBundle\Entity\Classification\Tag[] $tags
 */
public function setTags($tags)
{
    $this->tags = $tags;
}
```

then edit the doctrine xml located [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.4-develop/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Media.Media.orm.xml) to include these new relationships

**AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\Media.Media.orm.xml**

```
<many-to-many field="tags" target-entity="\AppBundle\Entity\Classification\Tag">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist/>
        </cascade>
        <join-table name="media__media_tag">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="media_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" unique="false" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="tag_id" referenced-column-name="id" column-definition="INT NULL" />
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

notice we're creating a new join table called `media__media_tag` this is following the existing patter and prefixing the table with `media__` and `media_tag` indicates the relationship.

we have solved the part of extending the current schema. You'll then need to tell the bundle to use your class instead as seen [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.4-develop/app/config/sonata/sonata_media.yml) (this could be in your `app/config/config.yml` instead of being imported from `app/config/sonata/sonata_media.yml` like the sandbox

```
sonata_media:
class:
    media:             AppBundle\Entity\Media\Media
```

The last step would be to add the property to the MediaAdmin class for management. This part is a little more tricky and I'm not sure if its the most ideal solution.

MediaBundle has an admin class for each storage model `ORM|ODM|PHPCR` implementing the abstract class [BaseMediaAdmin](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Admin/BaseMediaAdmin.php) unfortunately we would have to extend each one *used*. I beleive ORM is the most common so we'll extend [that one](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Admin/ORM/MediaAdmin.php)

what we are looking to do is add a form field for the tags

so creating a new directory `Admin` inside `AppBundle` and a class called `MediaAdmin` (or whatever you like as long as it ends in Admin) and extend the class `Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\ORM\MediaAdmin`. The example below we override configureFormFields and call the parent before adding the field for tags.

**AppBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

class MediaAdmin extends \Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\ORM
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);

        $formMapper->add('tags', 'sonata_type_model', array('multiple' => true, 'by_reference' => false));
    }
```

then we need to add a compiler pass to override the MediaAdmin service with our class.

**AppBundle\AppBundle.php**

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

**AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use AppBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('sonata.media.admin.media');
        $definition->setClass(MediaAdmin::class);
    }
}
```

if you wanted to add a tag filter you could override `configureDatagridFilters`, but this should be everything needed to get you started.

Comment: Thanks....i will try this...this helps me very much. 
I didnt use OverrideServiceCompilerPass before, that is a great way to do it

Comment: It's just the class name I chose. You can use any name you'd like

Comment: Thanks @StrikeForceZero This is working for me. I searched this solution for one week. Finally I got it from your answer. Thank a lot!!!